# How to assign individual values to multiple variable in single input prompt

Tags: matlab, variables

Say I want to assign values to dimension variables x and y in single input prompt that goes like,

```
'Enter x and y'
```

We do it this way in C

```
scanf(%f,%f,&x,&y)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have `input` return a string and then parse that string with `sscanf` two yield a two-element array which we can then assign to `x` and `y`.

```
str = input('Please enter two numbers: ', 's');
nums = sscanf(str, '%f,%f');
x = nums(1);
y = nums(2);
```

Alternately, you could just prompt the user to enter the data in a specific format  which will automatically create a cell array

```
nums = input('Enter two numbers in the form {num1, num2}');
[x, y] = nums{:};
```